# Malformed input or input contains unmappable characters wiki/... french characters

Tags: gitlab, sonarqube, gitlab-ci, pom.xml, sonar-runner

I have a gitlab-ci step that fails because of a sonar error,

The gitlab-ci command:

```
mvn $MAVEN_SETTINGS clean install sonar:sonar -Dsonar.host.url=$SONAR_URL -Dsonar.login=xxxx  -Dsonar.password=xxxx -Dsonar.projectKey=xxx -Dsonar.qualitygate.wait=true
```

I am getting this following error because of some files that contains french letters:

```
172820 [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.9.1.2184:sonar (default-cli) on project app-back: Malformed input or input contains unmappable characters: wiki/Base-de-donn��es-H2-pour-JDD-fictifs.md -> [Help 1]
```

I tried to add the wiki folder to sonar exclusions but I keep getting the error

in pom.xml:

```
<properties>
   <sonar.exclusions>src/main/resources/static/**/*, wiki/**/*</sonar.exclusions>
</properties>
```

The project structure:

```
app-back
  |_ java_submodule1
  |_ java_submodule2
  |_ wiki
      |_ Base-de-données-H2-pour-JDD-fictifs.md
  |_pom.xml
```

Could you please help me with a solution?